# React Native - function captures old hook value

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I encountered an issue where function captures state variable:

```
const SignIn = ({componentId}) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState(false);
    ...
    const getEmail = event => {
        setEmail(event);
        if (emailError && email.length > 0){
          setEmailError(false);
        }
    };
    .....
}
```

The problem is that getEmail function captures emailError and email variables. So when the "getEmail" runs for the first time, it correctly acts on right (latest) email and emailError. However, when the function runs for the second time, it refers to wrong (old) email and emailError since the function still has captured the old value.

If anyone know how to avoid this problem or have tips, please let me know. I appreciate for your help.

Comment: How are you calling `getEmail` function?

Comment: This is used in TextInput's onChangeText, which basically runs upon text change in TextInput

Comment: Try this `if (!emailError && email.length > 0)`, also where are you setting `emailError` to `true`?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
 const SignIn = ({componentId}) => {
 const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
 const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState(false);
 ...
 const getEmail = event => {
    setEmail(event);
    if (emailError && email.length > 0){
      setEmailError(false);
      setEmail("");
    }
};
.....
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your condition,

```
if (emailError && email.length > 0){
```

You are setting `email` and in very next step you are trying to access the `email`.

Due to `async` nature of `setState`, updated `email` will not be available to your condition.

You can try this,

```
const getEmail = event => {
    setEmail(event);
    if (emailError && event.length > 0){
      setEmailError(false);
    }else{
      setEmailError(true);
    }
};
```